# extern const linkage specification being seemingly ignored by G++

Tags: c++, linker, g++, name-mangling

I have a situation building a C codebase with a C++ compiler that parallels this:

**lib.h**

```
extern int const values[2] = {1, 2};
```

**lib.c**

```
#include "lib.h"
```

**main.c**

```
#include <iostream>

extern int const values[2];

int main() {
    std::cout << values[0] << ":" << values[1] << std::endl;
}
```

I had to add the extern because of something pointed out in the [C++03 Standard Annex C Compatibility C.1.2 Clause 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9032552/211160).  *(Compiling with `-fpermissive` will sweep this under the rug.)*

Incidentally the difference it makes in how `values` appears in objdump is like this before the `extern`:

```
$ objdump -t lib.o | grep values
0000000000000000 l     O .rodata    0000000000000008 _ZL6values

$ objdump -t main.o | grep values
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 values
```

...and then it's like this after it is added:

```
$ objdump -t lib.o | grep values
0000000000000000 g     O .rodata    0000000000000008 values

$ objdump -t main.o | grep values
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 values
```

So the name mangling was dropped, we see an "L" turn into a "G", and the linker does not complain about `values` being undefined.

---

Now imagine same situation with two very similar files, modified in the same way:

**tmp-exttypes.h**

```
extern const REBYTE Reb_To_RXT[REB_MAX] = { /* bunch of stuff */ };
```

**a-lib.c**

```
extern const REBYTE Reb_To_RXT[REB_MAX];
```

These are the only two Reb_To_RXT definitions in the project, built clean.  But it's not linking and when I objdump the only two files that mention it I get:

```
$ objdump -t a-lib.o | grep Reb_To_RXT
00000000         *UND*  00000000 Reb_To_RXT

$ objdump -t f-extension.o | grep Reb_To_RXT
00000080 l     O .rodata    00000038 _ZL10Reb_To_RXT
```

It says L, and it's name mangled.  Which didn't make the much simpler example happy.  But I'm wondering how this could happen with the extern on it at every appearance.  Am I right to believe this is a smoking gun...and is it generally not supposed to happen that something  only declared as extern should not have local linkage, anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i can't make sense of what you *ask*.

but …

having

```
extern int const values[2] = {1, 2};
```

in a header file, you have UB if that header is included in more than one translation unit. most likely but not necessarily you will then get a linking error.

one solution: declare the array in the header, like

```
extern int const values[2];
```

but define it (with initializer) in the implementation file.

another solution is to use the template trick or the inline function trick to define the array in the header file.

the inline function trick:

```
typedef int const Values[2];

inline Values& valuesRef()
{
    static Values   theValues = {1, 2};
    return theValues;
}

static Values& values = valuesRef();
```

Comment: Would have preferred a prototype and then a single definition of course, which is how I'd have done it.  But the code I'm adapting is someone else's C and it might be an uphill battle to get them to change it.  But if there's a citation that it's UB even in C then I might have more ammunition...?  :-/

Comment: @HostileFork In C++11 you can also declare the array as `constexpr` and initialize it. But, defining a global object twice violates the ODR and is instant UB.

Comment: @HostileFork: N869, the last draft (I believe) of C99, §6.9/5: "An external definition is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function or an object. If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than
as part of the operand of a sizeof operator), somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one." There is a later standard, C11, but I can't imagine that something so fundamental has changed. MSVC implements only C89 (not C99, but C89)...

Comment: by the way, `inline` is a quite different beast in C than in C++. i am not familiar with the C meaning. i am not sure you can do the header-only definition in C...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, correct.

The file you (I) were editing was auto-generated and actually destroyed by a clean make, which was noticed halfway writing down the thought process.  That "tmp" you see in that particular header was supposed to hint toward "temporary, do not edit", and if the file doesn't reload in the editor you're using it can be confusing.

*(Finished up the train of thought anyway for the institutional knowledge.  :-P)*